# Table creation limit for a data set in big query per day

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to test some thing in big query, so that I want to create more than 500k tables in a single data ser in big query in a day. Is there any hard limit for a day for table creation in big query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you are creating your tables using a load job, you only have [100k per day per project](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) (including failures)

Comment: I want to know the hard limit for table creation, not load jobs?
Either if its a empty table also, I want to know the limit.

Comment: There is no explicit limit for empty table creation frequency, but if you are planning to do it programmatically, a CREATE table is a load job

Comment: The limit is preventive to avoid the users from misusing BigQuery so in the end it can be increased with the proper purpose and after the proper request to the Google Cloud Platform Support.